# How to find the index of an object key in JSON Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON file

```
[
{
    "tag": "greetings",
    "words": ["hey", "hi", "sup"],
    "response": "Hi"
},
{
    "tag": "goodbye",
    "words": ["bye", "cya"],
    "response": "See you"
}
]
```

and I want to find for example the response that is placed with the key "cya", in this case "See you", or the tag, that would be "goodbye".
In the word "sup", it would be response "Hi".

Comment: There is no key `cya`. It's an element of the array in the `words` property.

Comment: You shouldn't ask for people to do your work for you, you should be trying to figure it out yourself. After you've tried to figure it out, if you still can't do it, post what you're trying, and then ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to find the entire object structure you have defined in the array, and return it on any word match in the words array.
You can do this using [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```py
json_obj = [{
    "tag": "greetings",
    "words": ["hey", "hi", "sup"],
    "response": "Hi"
}, {
    "tag": "goodbye",
    "words": ["bye", "cya"],
    "response": "See you"
}]

def find_by_word(findWord):
    for obj in json_obj:
        if findWord in obj["words"]:
            return obj

result = find_by_word("cya")
print(result)
```

Note that you could also give the `jsonObj` as a parameter of the function, and then you could call it, per example, as `findByWord(someJsonObj, someWordToFind)`

Comment: Hi, I am actually using python instead of javascript, anyways thanks for your answer.

Comment: Wow I'm so sorry, I have updated the answer with python :)

Comment: Omg, it worked, thank you very much!! I really spent time in this but didn't find anything, of course, I should've had use for loop